# Can't write multiple code blocks in a single <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand `javascript`. Why am I not allowed to do the code bellow ? When I try to do that, the `Block 01`doesn't work/render.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Page is now ready, initialize calenda.
    $('#calendario').fullCalendar({

        header: false,                  

        events: [
            {
                title: 'Event1',
                start: ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia,
                end: ano + '-' + mes + '-' + dia + 'T04:00'
            }
        ],

    });
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#calendario').fullCalendar(
        'renderEvent',
        {
            title: 'Teste',
            start: '2016-04-06',
        }
    );
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work/render`? `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` gets executed **only once** when the `document is ready`.

Comment: What type of code do you have in your `$(document).ready( ... );` call? I assume you have jQuery included already. The two functions you have should work fine - https://jsfiddle.net/o6scLL20/

Comment: @mark.hch updated with real code... The Calendar does not Render if I write the `Block 02`. Is it ok to right those blocks inside a single `<script>` 
?

Comment: You should put the `.click()` call inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Barmar Could you tell me what is the difference exactly ? Performance? Good Practice?

Comment: If you don't put it inside `$(document).ready()` then it runs before the DOM is fully loaded, and the `#btn` element might not exist yet. Unless you put all this code at the end of the document.

Comment: It's the same reason you put the call to `.fullCalendar()` inside `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code works fine; one thing to note is FullCalendar *requires* moment.js to be included. Basically the order of things to include are the FullCalendar CSS (in your `<head>` tag preferably), then jQuery.js, moment.js, and fullcalendar.js (just before your `</body>` tag preferably). All in all, you would need this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar.css'>
</head>
<body>
<button id='btn'>Click</button>
<div id='calendario'></div>

<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='moment.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script>
//Your code here
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The functioning fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqw1m9tb/